# Integration Testing with Spring Boot, RabbitMQ and UUID as primary key

Tags: spring, spring-boot, junit, rabbitmq, integration-testing

I have a Spring Boot application written in Kotlin with RabbitMQ and PostgreSQL. Primary keys in the DataBase are of type UUID and are generated by the application with a distinct service.

For integration testing this service is stubbed to generate UUIDs sequentionally instead of randomly, because they are checked against the expected data set. There is a simple incremental counter in the service.

This stub service has Prototype scope to every repository have its own UUID generator.

This approach had worked perfectly until I had to test cases with RabbitMQ.
The flow is following:

1. A request to controller is performed.
2. A record is saved in operations history table.
3. A message is sent to the RabbitMQ topic.
4. Then message is returned back to the application.
5. A new record is saved in operations history table.

When this test is run alone it passes and everything works as expected.
When this test is run together with the other tests it fails. An error occurs on step 5 when it tries to save new record to the data base.

Via debug I have discovered the following:
In the first case when the test is run alone the repository instance and the UUID generator service instance are the same on both steps 2 and 5.
In the second case when test is run together with the other, the repository instance and the UUID generator service instance are different on steps 2 and 5. As result there are different counters that are not syncronized. It leads to generation of the same id and a primary key exception on step 5.

As I understand this issue happens because Spring RabbitMQ creates listener containers that may have its own bean instances. It is still a riddle to me how it chooses to create a new bean instance or to use the existing.

Can you propose any solution or a different approach to implement this test?